# Scala use case with factory functions

Tags: scala

I'm writing a Scala app in which I want to construct objects from textual data. The base class is PageElement:

```
class PageElement {
  def make(buf: String): Option[PageElement]
}
```

The objects will be of subclass types, for instance

```
case class PeTypeA(val i: Int) extends PageElement {
    def make(buf: String): Option[PageElement] = {
        // simple example
        if (buf.length > 10) {
            Some(PeTypeA(11))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

case class PeTypeB(val s: String) extends PageElement {
    def make(buf: String): Option[PageElement] = {
        // simple example
        if (buf.length <= 10) {
            Some(PeTypeB("foo"))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a function `doIt` that takes a string as input, and calls the `make` function on each subclass in turn. The first `make` function that returns Some will be the output of `doIt`.

I figure that `make` ought to be a static function on each class, like

```
object PeTypeA {
   def make(buf: String): Option[PeTypeA] = ... 
}
```

But then I don't know how to make a list of these functions that I would iterate through inside `doIt`.

Comment: It sounds like you want to iterate through all known `object`s that extend `PageElement` without actually listing them inside the `doIt` function. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm okay with listing them inside `doIt`. Is it possible to construct a list of `object`s? you mean the `object` statements, right? In Python, I might have a list of classes, and iterate over them, calling a static function on each one.

Comment: List of `object`s? Sure. `Seq(ObA, ObB, ObC).map(_.make(""))` But, of course, you probably don't want to `map()` them. A `foldLeft()` might do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is similar to @tsearcher's but a bit different.

I would say that you should do what Scala standard collections do i.e. introduce a new trait `PageElementFactory` that will be implemented by companion objects:

```
trait PageElementFactory[+T <: PageElement] {
  def make(buf: String): Option[T]
}

case class PeTypeA(val i: Int) extends PageElement {
}

object PeTypeA extends PageElementFactory[PeTypeA] {
  override def make(buf: String): Option[PeTypeA] = {
    // simple example
    if (buf.length > 10) {
      Some(PeTypeA(11))
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}

case class PeTypeB(val s: String) extends PageElement {
}

object PeTypeB extends PageElementFactory[PeTypeB] {
  override def make(buf: String): Option[PeTypeB] = {
    // simple example
    if (buf.length <= 10) {
      Some(PeTypeB("foo"))
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}
```

and then you may use it as this:

```
abstract class PageElement {
}

object PageElement {
  private val allFactories: List[PageElementFactory[PageElement]] = List(PeTypeA, PeTypeB)

  def doIt(buf: String): Option[PageElement] = {
    allFactories.foldLeft[Option[PageElement]](None)((acc, fact) => acc.orElse(fact.make(buf)))
  }
}
```

If there are many various subtypes and performance is important, you may write `doIt` as

```
  def doIt(buf: String): Option[PageElement] = {

    @tailrec
    def impl(factories: List[PageElementFactory[PageElement]]): Option[PageElement] = factories match {
      case f :: rest => f.make(buf) match {
        case ope@Some(pe) => ope
        case None => impl(rest)
      }
      case Nil => None
    }

    impl(allFactories)
  }
```

This version will do a few less iterations in case of success.

The bonus of the `PageElementFactory` being a generic is that if you have a complicated nesting structure of nodes like in HTML where some nodes can have only certain types of children you may be able to express this using types by having several collections instead of single `allFactories`. Like if you have `PeTypeA` that can only have children of types `PeTypeA1` or `PeTypeA2`, than you may also have

```
abstract class PeTypeAChild extends PageElement {
}

class PeTypeA1 extends PeTypeAChild {
}

object PeTypeA1 extends PageElementFactory[PeTypeA1] {
  override def make(buf: String): Option[PeTypeA1] = ???
}
class PeTypeA2 extends PeTypeAChild {
}
object PeTypeA2 extends PageElementFactory[PeTypeA2] {
  override def make(buf: String): Option[PeTypeA2] = ???
}
```

and then

```
object PageElement {

  def doItImpl[T <: PageElement](buf: String, factories: List[PageElementFactory[T]]): Option[T] = {
    factories.foldLeft[Option[T]](None)((acc, fact) => acc.orElse(fact.make(buf)))
  }

  private val aChildFactories: List[PageElementFactory[PeTypeAChild]] = List(PeTypeA1, PeTypeA2)

  def doItA(buf: String): Option[PeTypeAChild] = doItImpl(buf, aChildFactories)

  private val allFactories: List[PageElementFactory[PageElement]] = List(PeTypeA, PeTypeA1, PeTypeA2, PeTypeB)

  def doIt(buf: String): Option[PageElement] = doItImpl(buf, allFactories)
}
```

Note how `doItA` returns more specific `Option[PeTypeAChild]`.

If this is complicated tree structure is not your case, you may simplify the code by using a non-generic `PageElementFactory` instead:

```
trait PageElementFactory {
  def make(buf: String): Option[PageElement]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```
sealed trait PageElement

case class PeTypeA(i: Int) extends PageElement

case class PeTypeB(s: String) extends PageElement

object PeTypeA {

  def make(buf: String): Option[PageElement] = {
    // simple example
    if (buf.length > 10) {
      Some(PeTypeA(11))
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}

object PeTypeB {

  def make(buf: String): Option[PageElement] = {
    // simple example
    if (buf.length <= 10) {
      Some(PeTypeB("foo"))
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}

def doIt(buf: String): Option[PageElement] = {
  PeTypeA.make(buf).orElse(PeTypeB.make(buf))
}

val a: Option[PageElement] = doIt("abcdefghijk")
val b: Option[PageElement] = doIt("abcdefghij")

a.foreach(println) // PeTypeA(11)
b.foreach(println) // PeTypeB(foo)
```